# Update fields with multiple values ​from different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

Product_categories (created from a *.csv* import). The limit number of categories in subcategories is 4.

```
product_reference | category_id | subcategories

REF.001           | 1           | 1/2
```

Categories (created from a *.csv* import)

```
id | name

1  | example_category_1
2  | example_category_2
```

Importer* (created to store all the data I need from the previous tables)

```
sku     | category

REF.001 | null
```

How could I update **Importer** to show the following? The limit number of categories in subcategories is 4.

```
sku     | category

REF.001 | example_category_1>example_category_2
```

*Data in **Importer** would be to export in .csv and be able to import in WooComerce, this is why I need to import the categories by this way. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/#section-4

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is the value in the subcategories field in Product_categories = `1/2`? And the value you want to finish with is `example_category_1>example_category_2`? If that is the case, then it's tricky. Can you change your schema to have two records in Product_categories, differing only by the values in the subcategories attribute - i.e. `1` for one record and `2` for the other?

Comment: Yes, the value in `subcategories` is `1/2`. And yes, the value i want to finish with is `example_category_1>example_category_2`

Comment: Is there an upper limit for the number of subcategories per category?

Comment: Yes, the limit number of categories in subcategories is 4

Comment: Do You want to perform update using single query? or stored procedure is safe solution? Does `Product_categories.subcategories` can contain `>` symbol? Does `Categories.name` can contain `/` symbol?

Comment: `Product_categories.subcategories` only contain `/` symbol and `Categories.name` doesnt contain any symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full example.

1) Create tables and data (code)

```
CREATE TABLE Product_categories (product_reference VARCHAR(8), category_id INT, subcategories VARCHAR(8));
INSERT INTO Product_categories VALUES
    ('REF.001',1,'1/2'),
    ('REF.002',2,'1/2/3/4');

CREATE TABLE Categories (id INT, name VARCHAR(32));
INSERT INTO Categories VALUES
    (1,'example_category_1'),
    (2,'example_category_2'),
    (3,'example_category_3'),
    (4,'example_category_4');

CREATE TABLE Importer (product_reference VARCHAR(8), category VARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO Importer (product_reference) VALUES
    ('REF.001'),
    ('REF.002');
```

2) Check data (console output)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Product_categories;
+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
| product_reference | category_id | subcategories |
+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
| REF.001           |           1 | 1/2           |
| REF.002           |           2 | 1/2/3/4       |
+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Categories;
+------+--------------------+
| id   | name               |
+------+--------------------+
|    1 | example_category_1 |
|    2 | example_category_2 |
|    3 | example_category_3 |
|    4 | example_category_4 |
+------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Importer;
+-------------------+----------+
| product_reference | category |
+-------------------+----------+
| REF.001           | NULL     |
| REF.002           | NULL     |
+-------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

3) Perform update (code)

```
UPDATE Importer i, (SELECT pc.product_reference,GROUP_CONCAT(c.name ORDER BY n.n SEPARATOR '>') category
                    FROM (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) n 
                    JOIN Product_categories pc
                    JOIN Categories c ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT('',pc.subcategories,'////'),'/',n.n),'/',-1) = c.id
                    GROUP BY pc.product_reference
                   ) d
SET i.category = d.category
WHERE i.product_reference = d.product_reference;
```

4) Check result (console output)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Importer;
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| product_reference | category                                                                    |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REF.001           | example_category_1>example_category_2                                       |
| REF.002           | example_category_1>example_category_2>example_category_3>example_category_4 |
+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer. When I ejecute the update code in my phpMyAdmin console, it says:  
`An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 19)`  
`Unexpected symbol (token) (near "(" at position 19)`
`A new declaration was found, but there is no delimiter between this and the previous one. (near "SELECT" at position 20)`
`Unexpected symbol (token) (near ")" at position 444)`
`Unexpected symbol (token) (near "d" at position 446)`
`A new declaration was found, but there is no delimiter between this and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 449)`

Comment: Throw out Your phpMyAdmin. It tries to show his intellect, which is absent. It cannot execute a lot of semantically correct types of queries.

Comment: If it's possible in phpMyAdmin, execute the query while disabling syntax checking and sending query text directly to MySQL without modifications.

Comment: My bad. Importer first column is ´sku´ and not ´product_reference´. Edited and solved. Thank you guys!

Comment: Oh... this is impossible to predict.